# Why SIGALRM triggers semaphore?

Tags: linux, signals, semaphore

I am a new man in linux programming. I did the following experiment and found a curious phenomenon: I set a timer in the program, when it times out, it triggers the semaphore, but I didn't use the function "sem_post" in the timer_handler. Can anyone explain the reason? How can I block the SIGALRM in semaphore? Thank you.
The following is my code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <signal.h>

int count = 1;
sem_t job_queue;

void timer_handler(int signum)
{
    printf("time out...\n");
}

void init_timer_signal_action()
{
    struct sigaction timer_act;
    timer_act.sa_handler = timer_handler;
    timer_act.sa_flags  = 0;

    sigemptyset(&timer_act.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &timer_act, NULL);
}

void init_timer()
{
    struct itimerval value;
    value.it_value.tv_sec=5;
    value.it_value.tv_usec=0;
    value.it_interval=value.it_value;
    setitimer(ITIMER_REAL,&value,NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    init_timer_signal_action();
    init_timer();

    sem_init(&job_queue, 0, 0);

    while(1)
    {
        sem_wait(&job_queue);
        printf("Now count is: %d.\n", count++);
    }

    sem_destroy(&job_queue_count);
    return 0;
}
```

The following is the results of running the program:
time out...
Now count is: 1.
time out...
Now count is: 2.
time out...
Now count is: 3.
time out...
Now count is: 4.
time out...
Now count is: 5.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "triggers the semaphore".  It looks like all that is happening is that `sem_wait` is returning.  Check the return value.

Answer (score 1):

> Why SIGALRM triggers semaphore?

It is expected behaviour. From the [sem_wait manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_wait.3.html):

> the call blocks
> until either it becomes possible to perform the decrement (i.e.,
> the semaphore value rises above zero), or a signal handler
> interrupts the call.

Many system calls are interruptible by signals. Some system calls, including `sem_wait` can be automatically restarted by establishing the signal handler with `SA_RESTART`. Read the [signal manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) for more details. Here's an excerpt:

> **Interruption of system calls and library functions by signal handlers**
>
> If a signal handler is invoked while a system call or library
> function call is blocked, then either:
>
> - the call is automatically restarted after the signal handler
>   returns; or
> - the call fails with the error EINTR.
>
>   Which of these two behaviors occurs depends on the interface and
>   whether or not the signal handler was established using the
>   SA_RESTART flag (see sigaction(2)).  The details vary across UNIX
>   systems; below, the details for Linux.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.